# Unable to start Docker based on Ubuntu or Debian

Tags: ubuntu, docker, docker-compose

I tried to create my own container based on Ubuntu (and the same with Debian). I use `docker-compose` to manage my containers and I use `dockerfile` to create my container.

When I use the `docker-compose` to create and start my container, I always had  a status `Exited 0` (without information in logs or on my screen and when I create and start with a simple docker command, it works well.

Do you have an idea why ?

**My dockerfile**

```
ENV DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive
RUN apt-get -y update
RUN apt-get -y upgrade
RUN apt-get install -y sqlite3 libsqlite3-dev apache2 php php-sqlite3
RUN /usr/bin/sqlite3 /etc/apache2/db/test.db
RUN apt-get clean autoclean
RUN apt-get autoremove --yes
RUN rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*
CMD /bin/bash
```

**My docker-compose**

```
bdd:
container_name: bdd
build: /docker/bdd
image: image_bdd:latest
```

Comment: What are the exact commands you're running with those files to get the results you describe.

Answer (score 1):

Thank for you answers. I forgot to put it in my question, but the line `FROM ubuntu:latest` was present.
To answer, I found the solution with the CMD line, because you can find a lot of version on the internet :

```
CMD ["/usr/sbin/apache2ctl", "-DFOREGROUND"]
```

The line `CMD ["/bin/bash"]` didn't work well. Do you have some ideas why ?

Answer (score 0):

`FROM` directive is missing in the Dockerfile

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify from what image do you want to work.

Try to modify the Dockerfile [like these](https://github.com/dockerfile/ubuntu/blob/master/Dockerfile):

```
FROM ubuntu:latest

RUN apt-get -y update && \
    apt-get -y upgrade && \
    apt-get install -y sqlite3 libsqlite3-dev apache2 php php-sqlite3 && \
    /usr/bin/sqlite3 /etc/apache2/db/test.db && \
    apt-get clean autoclean && \
    apt-get autoremove --yes && \
    rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

ENV DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive

CMD ["/bin/bash"]
```

The docker-compose file needs to be [like these](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#build):

```
version: '3'
services:
  bdd:
    build: /docker/bdd/
```